# Overlay 2 DIVs where one is Static and the other is Scrollable

Tags: css

I am creating a page where the Hero image must stay centered on screen as the visitor scrolls down the page.  Elements that are scrollable will 'frame' the Hero image as they scroll past.

However, my initial screen (above-the-fold) must have the Hero image, and the first Frame image, overlaid, and no matter how I mix position: sticky with fixed, absolute, static... Nothing will work, and the Frame appears below the Hero (i.e. the div will not overlap/overlay).

Also, I want the Frame layer in front of the Hero, but z-index appears to make no difference.

here is my layout:

```
<div class="homepage">
    <div class="hero-image">
        <img src="images/hero-can.png">
    </div>
    <div class="homeScreen1">
        <img src="images/water-splash.png">
    </div>
 </div>
```

here is my CSS:

```
.homepage {
    background-image: url('images/background.jpg');
}

.hero-image {
    margin: 0 auto;
    max-width: 512px;
    position: sticky;
    top: 0;
    z-index: 99999;
}

.homeScreen1 {
    margin: 0 auto;
    width: 1024px;
    text-align: center;
    z-index: 999999;
}
```

Appreciate any help!!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can achieve that with these steps:

1. Set the `position` of the container (i.e. homepage) to `relative`.
2. Set the `position` of the hero to `fixed`, so it doesn't scroll with the container.
3. Set the `position` of the frames to `absolute` with `z-index` higher than the hero so it can overlay it.

You can see the example below. I set the container background color so we can see it and set its height to `1000px` so we can test it scrolling, so those settings are for demo purpose only.

To center your hero and frames, you need these steps:

1. Set the left and right margins to `auto`.
2. Set a fixed width. This is required for the auto margins to work.
3. Set the `left` and `right` to zero. This is required for `fixed` and `absolute` layouts to be centered.

```css
.homepage {
    background-color: #0ff;
    height: 1000px;
    position: relative;
}

.hero-image {
    position: fixed;
    width: 150px;
    margin: 0 auto;
    left: 0;
    right: 0;
}

.homeScreen1 {
    position: absolute;
    width: 160px;
    margin: 0 auto;
    top: 200px;
    left: 0;
    right: 0;
    z-index: 1;
}
```

```html
<div class="homepage">
    <div class="hero-image">
        <img src="http://placehold.it/150x150">
    </div>
    <div class="homeScreen1">
        <img src="http://placehold.it/160x160">
    </div>
 </div>
```

Comment: Yes, that worked for my Layout code, thanks.  My issue was in getting the initial overlay to work - I could make the Frame scoll 'past' the Hero as I wanted it to, but I just couldn't make it START ovarlaid.  Thanks, worked perfectly :)